# Field @timestamp using Spring Data ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

What I am trying to achieve:

- insert document in ElasticSearch using Reactive Spring Data ElasticSearch with a field `@timestamp` (note the "at" @ sign for timestamp, it is `@timestamp`, not just timestamp).

What I tried:

```
@Repository
public interface ElasticRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<ElasticPojo, String> {

}
```

```
@Document(indexName = "theindex")
public class ElasticPojo {

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private long timestamp;

    @Id
    private String id;
```

Issue:

This will insert a `timestamp` field inside ElasticSearch, not `@timestamp`

How to insert a field `@timestamp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.annotations) for the `@Field` annotation, it has a `name` parameter:

```java
@Field(name = "@timestamp", type = FieldType.Date)
```